# JS: Convert XML or JSON to XML/RDF

Tags: javascript, xml, json, xml-parsing, rdf

In JavaScript, what's the easiest way to convert a String that holds XML or JSON into an XML/RDF file? I know I will probably have to use String parsing, but has this already been done or is there an easier way? I can find resources online on how to convert to RDF, but nothing about how to do it within JavaScript (IE: http://www.gac-grid.de/project-products/Software/XML2RDF.html) Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we please see what you have tried please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [rdfquery](https://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/) or [rdfparser](http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2005/ajar/release/tabulator/0.7/rdf/rdfparser.js) fits your need, I did not use them and seem very old.

On the client side, we use [json-ld](http://json-ld.org/)